# Serverless 3 project newly upgraded from 2 - cannot update stack / cannot create new changeset

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless

I've been using Serverless for about a year and a half - I love it.
Recently two projects were upgraded from version 2 to 3.
The first deploy worked fine, but all subsequent ones are failing for the same reason.

The first thing that will happen is it will get to:

```
Waiting for new change set to be created
Change Set did not reach desired state, retrying
```

then this will repeat over and over.

```
Change Set did not reach desired state, retrying
```

So then I cancel the process and try again and then get:

```
Cannot delete ChangeSet in status CREATE_IN_PROGRESS
```

When I go to the AWS console and check on the stack - there are no changes, no failures, or any indication it tried to do anything.

The things I'm thinking but know I must be wrong about are:

1. Somehow it's got a completely different set of AWS credentials and has tried to create the stack in another account - This can't be correct because it worked one one stack.
2. It's not actually talking to AWS and thinks it needs to create the stack based on the lack of connection - surely it realises when this happens...  I've even tried without internet and got told so.

I'm so confused.  Any help will be massively appreciated!

[EDIT] Update - After waiting some time the message about CREATE_IN_PROGRESS will go back to the first message.

[EDIT2] It seems if I just let it fail for 5 mins it will eventually work

Comment: I have a similar issue. So far I've been able to find references to problem being caused by `serverless-esbuild` although it doesn't make much sense as it does not play a role in building a cloud formation template, but transpiling code

Comment: There is also this in serverless 3 documentation. 
The serverless deploy command internals for AWS provider has been changed and now use change sets. Due to that, the required IAM permissions for successfully running deployments have changed
https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/guides/upgrading-v3

Answer (score 0):

I was also upgrading the version to v3 and this same error happened. The thing I did was to delete the CloudFormation stack from the AWS console and run the deploy command again.

The deploy recreates the stack on CF and the command worked. After that I ran it again to validate, and the command execution were successful.